# Web scrape a updating value

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, request

I am new to python and I am trying to scrape a value that constantly updates. When you first enter the site the value says "laddar temperatur (loading temperature)" and then goes on to show the actual temperature after a while.  When I run my script the only thing I get is the "loading temperature" value. I am guessing that it has to do with the fact that the script reloads the site every time I run it. How do I get it so that it "stays" on the site and collect the information after the "loading temperature"?

Site: http://s-websrv02.lulea.se/ormberget/

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import time

r = requests.get("http://s-websrv02.lulea.se/ormberget/")

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")

match = soup.find("div", id="ReloadThis").text

for item in match:
print(match)
time.sleep(20)
```

Answer (score 0):

The temperature is fetched using XHR call.

The code below should return the temperature

```
import requests

r = requests.get('http://s-websrv02.lulea.se/ormberget/Orm_Stadium.php')
print(r.text.strip())
```

if you like to get the temperature value periodically do something like:

```
import time
import requests

collected_data = []
SLEEP_TIME = 5
while True:
    r = requests.get('http://s-websrv02.lulea.se/ormberget/Orm_Stadium.php')
    value = r.text.strip() if r.status_code == 200 else '-1000'
    collected_data.append({'time':time.time(), 'value':value})
    time.sleep(SLEEP_TIME)
```